# How to pass in two different variable id's inside a rails action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my Comments controller; comments belong to Topic and Post, and Topic and Post have many comments.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :require_sign_in

  before_action :authorize_user, only: [:destroy]

...
...
  def destroy

    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    topic_comment = @topic.comments.find(params[:id])

    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    post_comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

    if post_comment.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was deleted"
      redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
    elsif topic_comment.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was deleted"
      redirect_to @topic
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Comment counld't be deleted. Try again"
      redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
    end

  end

  private


  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def authorize_user
    comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    unless current_user == comment.user || current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to delete a comment."
      redirect_to [comment.post.topic, comment.post]
    end
  end

end
```

I have my routes built correctly, post.comments (seeds) and topic.comments (seeds) display correctly within my application.  The above action `destroy` worked when I only passed `@post`.  However, I receive errors now that I introduced `@topic`.  If I click on my delete button via `topic` I receive: (*Couldn't find Post without an ID*) in the browser.  Alternatively, I receive this error when clicking delete on my post.comment (which worked prior to the introduction of `@topic`): (*Couldn't find Topic with 'id'=*)

Should I create some type of loop within the destroy action, a method within the class, or another loop within a module?  Am I looking at this wrong and should try another idea?  I basically want to destroy my topic.comment when clicked and my post.comment went clicked.

Thanks

Comment: I think at a time only one will be present right ? either post_id or topic_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_sign_in
  before_action :authorize_user, only: [:destroy]

  def destroy
    @commentable = find_commentable
    @comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])

    if @comment.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Comment was deleted"
      redirect_to [@commentable.topic, @commentable]  
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Comment counld't be deleted. Try again"
      redirect_to [@commentable.topic, @commentable]  
    end
  end  

  private
  def find_commentable
    if params[:topic_id].present?
      Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    elsif params[:post_id].present?
      Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end
  end 

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

  def authorize_user
    comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    unless current_user == comment.user || current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "You do not have permission to delete a comment."
      redirect_to [comment.post.topic, comment.post]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
   @topic = Topic.find_by_id(params[:topic_id]) ##it will not raise an error if params[:topic_id] not present, returns either nil or object
   topic_comment = @topic.comments.find(params[:id]) if @topic.present?

    @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id]) ##it will not raise an error if params[:post_id] not present, returns either nil or object
    post_comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id]) if @topic.present?

##rest of your logic.
```